Is there any way to have redis and memchaced coexist on one server?
I'm currently running a web service on an aws web server (ec2).
I'm using elasticache memcached to keep the login status.
However, the screen loads very slowly, so I considered storing the query execution results in elasticache's redis.
The reason for choosing redis over memcached is that redis has a larger capacity than memcached, so we decided that redis was the appropriate place to store the query execution results.
Is it possible to use redis while keeping the existing login status in memcached? Or is it better to migrate the login state keeping itself to redis?
First, I was forced to install redis and memcahed to make them coexist.
I'm trying added redis to a web server that already has memcached,
I don't know why, but it is working... :(
But if you know, I would like to know the official procedure.
In php.ini, there is memcached connection information
session.save_handler = memcached

For some reason, /etc/php.d/ contains memcached and redis.
50-memcached.ini
50-redis.ini

I was able to install redis and run both memcached and redis with this procedure.

Install redis-cli on ec2

sudo yum install gcc
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
sudo make BUILD_TLS=yes


install pecl, the php package manager

sudo yum install php-pear


Install Redis client library phppredis

sudo yum install php-devel
sudo pecl install redis


Add extension to php.ini

sudo systemctl restart httpd

Environment information
php 8 (Codeigniter)
i am using AWS
WEB server: EC2 (3 units on each AZ) DB server: RDS (Aurora cluster mode)
Elasticache (redis(7.1.0) and memcached(1.5.16))
